# How to set an ingress with ClusterIP in AWS-EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am new to the AWS EKS and I want to know how I can setup an ingress and enable TLS (with a free service such as `lets-encrypt`).

I have deployed an `EKS` cluster and I have the following sample `nginx` manifest.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer.  // <------ can't I use a ClusterIp and still have a LB priovisioned?
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80        
---
#05-ALB-Ingress-Basic.yml
# Annotations Reference:  https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-usermgmt-restapp-service
  labels:
    app: usermgmt-restapp
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /usermgmt/health-status
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service-loadbalancer
            port:
              number: 80
```

When it creates the `LoadBalancer` type service, it go ahead and creates a `classic` load balancer.

My questions are:

1. How can I provision (automatically) a Layer7 application load balancer and not the `classic` load balancer
2. Instead of using `LoadBalancer` type service, can I use a `ClusterIP` service and use my ingress to point to that and still create an automatic Load Balancer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. How can I provision (automatically) a Layer7 application load
   balancer and not the classic load balancer

> By using an ingress resource and specifying `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"`.

2. Instead of using LoadBalancer type service, can I use a ClusterIP service and use my ingress to point to that and still
   create an automatic Load Balancer?

> yes, when used `alb` ingress resource with annotation `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip` you can use a clusterip service.

so please don't create both a service-type loadbalancer and ingress resource at the same time.

Comment: thanks! it worked for me. ChatGPT was taking me round and round.